Reverse engineering RC188 remote?
I'm trying to do a home automation project that involves a Decco ceiling fan. According to their website, that fan uses a RC188 remote controller. Due to WAF, I can't take the fan/remote apart. I'm struggling to find information on RC188 (or more like worried that I'm looking at wrong RC188 like https://www.manualslib.com/manual/940945/Emerson-Rc188.html).
Any information on what RC188 protocol is, and how to reverse engineer one?
EDIT:
The remote works if I put it in a cardboard (though somewhat less reliably). It also works if I go to the next room, close myself inside as long as I'm pointing in the direction of the fan. It works otherwise too, but a lot less reliably. Two rooms from the fan, the remote no longer works.
Also, each fan works with a specific remote (paired.) There's a little red light on the remote that blinks when I press anything.
Okay, so I decided to man up and take it apart. Here are some photos:
[




You could at least explain if it is infrared, RF,  wired, or some other type of remote. Then explain TLAs like WAF what they mean. Then, there may be an easy way to reverse engineer it.

I'm not sure what type of remote it is, which is what I'm trying to find out. I think it is Bluetooth, or may be a proprietary protocol. Each fan has a dedicated remote. It's as if like they are paired like with Bluetooth, which is why I thought it may be that. Sorry for not being able to give more info, I'm a complete newbie to wireless communication.

does the remote control work when placed inside a cardboard box?

do you have to flip switches inside the remote control,  and inside the receiver?

@jsotola Added some photos along with a bit more information.

research the FCC ID

According to the FCC registration it is a 433.92MHz device

WAF is Wife Acceptance Factor, a very important consideration for amateur engineering.
